# using xsl include a header file

Tags: c++

I had created a program using xsl as follows:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!-- Edited by XMLSpy® -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
#include<stdio>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am gettting the following errors:-
End tag 'xsl:template' does not match the start tag 'stdio'.

Please tell me how to solve the above errors?

Thanks & Regards
Vikas

Answer (score 1):

`<` and `>` have special meaning for XML parsers. Replace them with `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Generally do these replacements in the output:

> ```
> "   &quot;
> '   &apos;
> <   &lt;
> >   &gt;
> &   &amp;
> ```

After that your output will be like below:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
#include&lt;stdio&gt;
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

`include<stdio>` should be `#include&lt;stdio&gt;`. Validation on the xml is trying to treat the `<stdio>` portion as markup and therefore cannot find the end tag.